# Writing Ternary Expression to Match Specific If/Else in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

In doing an ETL to get data from a Sybase database into a MongoDB backend, I can do this:

```
if (data.hire_date) staffProfile.hireDate = data.hire_date;
```

This method prevents nulls from being populated into the MongoDB. If `data.hire_date` has a value, then it will be dropped into `staffProfile.hireDate`. However, if there is no value, it effectively is ignored.

Now, I'd like to create the same result with a ternary expression. Something like:

```
staffProfile.hireDate = data_hireDate ? data_hireDate : null;
```

However, I don't want to use `null` here, because when I do that I end up with a bunch of nulls in the database. My question really boils down to two things: what is effectively happening in my first example, with the "if" case, when the value is not found? Is the result `undefined`? What could I use in the ternary syntax example to effectively write the same conditional check - right through to what is passed when the value doesn't exist?

Would this be the equivalent expression to my first example?

```
staffProfile.hireDate = data_hireDate ? data_hireDate : undefined;
```

Comment: `staffProfile.hireDate: staffProfile.hireDate ?` This syntax doesn't make sense - the colon should come *after* the question mark in a ternary, not before

Comment: If you don't define it, it's undefined. What the DB and/or your code expects if there's no value, only you know that.

Comment: Use `=`, not `:`, when you're trying to assign a value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** *"What is effectively happening in my first example, with the "if" case, when the value is not found? Is the result `undefined`?"*

Yes, it will be `undefined`, if the condition doesn't get passed, and the object property is not created and nothing's assigned to it:

```js
const data = {};
const staffProfile = {};

if (data.hire_date) staffProfile.hireDate = data.hire_date;

console.log("data:", data);
console.log("staffProfile.hireDate:", staffProfile.hireDate);
```

**2.** *"What could I use in the ternary syntax example to effectively write the same conditional check - right through to what is passed when the value doesn't exist?"*

You can achieve absolutely the same result this way:

```js
const data = {};
const staffProfile = {};

data.hire_date ? staffProfile.hireDate = data.hire_date : null;

console.log("data:", data);
console.log("staffProfile.hireDate:", staffProfile.hireDate);
```

And not this way (it will become `null` in this case):

```js
const data = {};
const staffProfile = {};

staffProfile.hireDate = data.hire_date ? data.hire_date : null;

console.log("data:", data);
console.log("staffProfile.hireDate:", staffProfile.hireDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

if `date_hireDate` exits, it will be assigned to staffProfile.hireDate. The below syntax is what you want.

`staffProfile.hireDate = data_hireDate && data_hireDate`

However, it does not make sense. `date_hireDate` before `&&` operator should be a condition like `date_hireDate === something`.